# Pass 2 parameters to function in ClientTemplate of Telerik grid in Asp.net mvc3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid, client-templates

I want to send two parameters to a function in a ClientTemplate of a Telerik Grid in Asp.net MVC3.

I did something like this:

```
 columns.Bound(m => m.ID).Title("Delete").ClientTemplate("<a href='#' title='Delete' onclick='return DeleteData(<#=ID#>,<#=Name#>)'><SPAN class='delete'></SPAN></a>").Width(53);
```

But this is not working.

In this `ID` field is an int field and `Name` is a string type field. How can I accomplish this task?
Can anyone please help me??????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my question myself.
It can be done like:

```
columns.Bound(m => m.ID).Title("Delete").ClientTemplate("<a href='#' title='Delete' onclick=\"return DeleteData(<#=ID#>,'<#=Name#>')\"><SPAN class='delete'></SPAN></a>").Width(53);
```

And its working

:-)

Comment: This issue is happening with me also. But i am unable to make it work.

Comment: Had the exact same problem today. You made my day by posting this! +1